# Passing # sharp character to dialing intent

Tags: android

The number desired to be called is `232323`, but i'm adding `#31#` to give the user an opportunity to call privately.

if i do this :

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:" + "232323"));
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It will work, however, if I do this :

```
   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:" + "#31#232323"));
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It won't.
How can I make it work?

Comment: What happens when you run the code you gave?

Comment: It worked as Vahid Farahmand suggested, I just tried it, thanks to Vahid! IF i run the code I gave, the dialer screen will show but without any number inside, null.

Comment: what i would LOVE to know is the reason my question has been low rated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("#31#232323")));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Love you bro, fastest answer.. 2 minutes left to accept your answer.. please can you tell me how did you think of it?? I mean... what made you think of encoding the number.. that's smart!

Comment: As you are using special chars, you may need to encode the URI, isn't it? :) glad I could help